# Enforcing the order of deployment in gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

This is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-grunt-plugin:0.13'
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.scobal.eslint:gradle-eslint-plugin:1.0.1"

    }
}
plugins{
    id "com.moowork.grunt" version "0.13"
    id "com.moowork.node" version "0.13"
}

// apply all plug-ins

apply plugin: 'com.moowork.grunt'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: "com.github.scobal.eslint"


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
//version = '24.1.1.0'

war.doFirst{
    deleteFiles()
    grunt_build()
    grunt_compile()
}
task deleteFiles(type: Delete){
    delete fileTree("${System.properties['TOMCAT_HOME']}/webapps"){
        include '**/*.war'
    }
}   

task deployToTomcat(type: Copy) {

    from war.archivePath
    into "${System.properties['TOMCAT_HOME']}/webapps"

}

deployToTomcat.doFirst{
    war()
}
clean.doFirst{
    deleteFiles
}

eslint {
    inputs = ["./src/**/*.js"]
}

// exclude the files we don't want to deliver
// TODO - is there an easier way to exclude all directories under js???  We don't want any of them.
war {
  exclude('src/js/main.js')
  exclude('src/js/actions')
  exclude('src/js/api')
  exclude('src/js/components')
  exclude('src/js/constants')
  exclude('src/js/dispatcher')
  exclude('src/js/stores')
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart' //,
                   //'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile("org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.3.RELEASE")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.4")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.4")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.4")
    compile("org.darkphoenixs:log4j:1.2.17")
    compile files('libs/opla230.jar')

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
```

The problem that's happening is that the deployToTomcat is running first and deploying an old war on the tomcat. After that the war task of the war plugin runs and generates a new war which never gets deployed. Can someone help me with the enforcing of the order of these actions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "dependsOn war" in your deployToTomcat task.

Comment: remove the block about deployToTomcat.doFirst{
    war()
}

Comment: I've modified that code in this manner, `task deployToTomcat(dependsOn: war) {
 copy{
  from "build/lib"
  into "${System.properties['TOMCAT_HOME']}/webapps"
  include "*.war"
 }      
}`